# Performance of UNION vs IN for partitioning key in Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Let's say we have the following Cassandra table:

```
create table news(
    date text,
    source text,
    category int,
    id text,
    title text,
    tags text,
    primary key ((date, source, category), id)
)
```

Now we need to support lookups by date, category and source:

```
select * from news where date in ('2019-01-23', '2019-01-24') and 
category in (1, 4, 6) and source in ('Bloomberg', 'CNN');
```

I have been told that this query will perform suboptimal comparing to 
the same where we split all IN groups into separate queries and join results using UNION (12 subqueries in case above). The reasoning is that UNION will be split into 12 independent queries and each of the can be process by one of the nodes in the cluster (20+ nodes) and we will start getting results faster. It was supposed to be faster also in case when we just wanted to make sure that number of rows returned is below some threshold:

```
select count(*) (
    select * from news where date in ('2019-01-23', '2019-01-24') and 
       category in (1, 4, 6) and source in ('Bloomberg', 'CNN') LIMIT 10001
);
```

However, I don't observe performance improvement both for small result sets and large ones (250K rows). I tried googling but couldn't find anything that could support or prove wrong UNION hypothesis.

I am using Spark SQL (Hive 2) and Java CQL driver to access data in Cassandra.

I would appreciate any helpful information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

couple of points,

1. If you are always going to filter category before source, its better to have the Schema also changed like ((date, category, source), id) because the order does matter.
2. The performance is not only based on the number of records you are trying and its more based on how many Partition keys are used on the call - the above example seems too little to prove a performance difference.
   If you can try the same scenario with much more partitions (say for example you want to filter 50 dates instead of 2), then you can see the IN getting worse.

Answer (score 0):

When you send 12 queries to a cluster of 12 nodes, there is a likelihood that the 12 nodes will independently get data and return it back via the coordinator. That's a proper distribution of work through parallel queries. That is why breaking up the queries is faster. If you don't have enough data or enough nodes, you may not ever see that difference.

If the partitions are large, regardless of how distributed, you may still get the same delays. Not knowing what the data looks like , how many total partitions you have, and  how many nodes you have, it's hard to tell which one is going to be faster for **you**.